# HTML/javascript TypeError when using document.getElementById even though ID's are declared

Tags: javascript, html

A button on my webpage stops working every few days and then starts working again without any intervention/modifying source code. This "Next" button calls a javascript function to iterate forward through an array of text already retrieved via php, but sometimes it stops working. I have not touched this code for more than a month, and during this time I have seen it working most of the time - but not always. Today it's not working.

Here is the button declaration:

```
<input type="button" value="Next Question" class="button" onclick="submitform('Next')" style=" padding: 0.25em 1em 0.25em 1em;" id="nextQButton"/>
```

The button calls function submitForm with parameter "Next."

```
function submitform(x)
    {
     document.getElementById("alertShow").innerHTML = ""


     if(x=='Back')
      {
      ....

      }

    else if(x=='Next') 
    {
    alert("next Q!");


    if(jj+1<numQQ){
                runningSum += qnumans_array[jj]; 
    }

    ++jj;
    ++j;
    kk=0;


    if (jj == limit)
    {

         if((viewQ==null)&&(viewA==null))
          {
              window.location="judge.php?counter="+j;   
          } 
          else if(viewQ) 
          {
              window.location="judge.php?&counter="+j+"&viewQ="+viewQ;
          }
          else if(viewA)
         {
             window.location="judge.php?&counter="+j+"&viewA="+viewA;
         }

   }           

   alert("middle of next q bit1"); 
   if( jj>=numQQ && jj!=limit)
   {      
       --jj;
       --j;
       alert("middle of next q bit if statement"); 
                 document.getElementById("alertShow").innerHTML = "end of available questions for this category";
   }

   alert("middle of next q bit2"); 
   alert("jj is"+jj);
   alert("qid array at jj is"+qid_array[jj]);
   document.getElementById('qidInput').value = qid_array[jj];  ///*****this is where it stops  outputting script alerts. all alerts before this output as they should.
    ***********************************************
   alert("middle of next q bit3"); 
   document.getElementById('jjInput').value = j;
   alert("middle of next q bit4"); 
   document.getElementById("questionShow").innerHTML = quser_array[jj] + ": "+ question_array[jj];         
   alert("middle of next q bit5"); 

   if(qnumans_array[jj]>0)
   {
        document.getElementById("answerShow").innerHTML = auser_array[kk + runningSum] + ": " + answer_array[kk + runningSum];
   }
   else
   {
         document.getElementById("answerShow").innerHTML = "No answers posted to this question."; 
    }

   alert("got to end of next q bit");  

    }
....
}
```

The line after which the alerts fail relates to this input field in an html form in the same php files:

```
  <input type = 'hidden' id = 'qidInput' name = 'qid' >
```

Chrome debugging tool gives me this error

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'value' of null
```

on every line that calls:

```
document.getElementById("qidInput").value = qid_array[jj];
```

Even though these similar calls generate no error:

```
document.getElementById("jjInput").value = j;
document.getElementById("kkInput").value = kk+runningSum;
```

All these HTML elements are declared together and are of the same type:

```
<form name="messageInput" id = 'idForm'  method="get" action="judge.php?" 
      onSubmit="return validate(this)">
      <center><textarea name='text' style="height: 1em"></textarea><br>
      <input type = 'hidden' id = 'qidInput' name = 'qid' >
      <input type = 'hidden' id = 'jjInput'  name = 'counter' >
      <input type = 'hidden' id = 'kkInput'  name = 'kk' >
    <ul class="actions">
  <li><input type="submit" value="Post Message" class="button"/></li> 
</ul> 
</center>
</form>
```

If I comment out every line that contains qidInput, the error message switches to giving the same error, now for every line that contains "jjInput." So it seems to be something about the ordering - whichever HTML element is called by id first is nil.

This happens on the same computer and browser on different days. The conditions on the webpage are the same, too.

Any debugging advice would be appreciated. Thank you.

Fixes that didn't work:
-swapping single and double quotes
-adding a "dummy" element and setting it first (so it's probably not ordering)

Comment: What happens when you run the debugger through it? Throw a breakpoint on the line before, and step through.

Comment: Use chrome debugging, you can see all your variables/values and exactly whats happening. I think its breaking because your data isnt get passed through, or unexpected data is being passed through.  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=c_oiQYirKuY

Comment: I think you must answer to three questions:1)are the browsers you work with the same? 2)are conditions when this error happen the same 3)doest js console show any errors?

Comment: @JoeEnos Thank you for your feedback. When I run it through the Chrome debugger, it says: Uncaught Type Error: Cannot set property 'value' of null. Which would seem to suggest I never declared the element with this id, but that is not the case - it's right there in the HTML plus the "back" button also adjusts the value of this element by id. I changed the single quotes to double quotes but that did not change the result:  document.getElementById("qidInput").value = qid_array[jj];